# How to figure out equations for a signal flux diagram?

Tags: circuit-design, signal, signal-processing, transfer-function

I have a signal flow diagram like the one below for a biquad NHK.  I'm trying to understand how to derive the equations \$\frac{v_1}{v_i}, \frac{v_2}{v_i}, \frac{v_3}{v_i}\$ from it.

I don't quite get the picture on how should I convert the diagram configuration to an equation. For example, what is supposed to be the \$\sum\$ signal in an equation? Is it the sum of the following transfer functions? What exactly is the \$\frac{-1}{sT}\$? How about the \$\frac{1}{Q}\$ - how is it interpreted?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbol Sigma is the sum of what "enter" in the block ...
i.e. \$ V1 = Vi * K + (-1) * V3 + V2 * (1/Q) \$

-1/( s * T) is an inverting integrator ...

Factors are an "amplifier" block. Just define the amplification factor.

The Q factor is a characteristic of the entire function (second-order equation). Defined as a parameter in simulation.

Here is the simulated function. Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm), interactive.
Only point out "define" line text and change value with up or down arrows.
Here, "stepping" is used.

[image]

Comment: I see! I understand where the expression for \$v_1\$ comes from - the block algebraic. But, as you mentioned, for \$v_2\$ I have the inverting integrator. So would it be written like \$V_1 (\frac{-1}{sT})\$?

Comment: Yes. I will add simulated function in answer.

Comment: You said Q factor is the solution to the second order equation? How can I find it? Would it be the cut frequency over the bandwidth?

Comment: No. Not the solution, sorry. Q is an important factor in the equation. As you can see, it is the parameter that fixes the "maxima" of the function. The function is a bandpass filter and the center frequency is not affected by Q.

Answer (score 2):

Hint to get you started: -

$$V_1 = KV_i + \dfrac{V_2}{Q} - V_3$$

And you can probably see that \$V_2 = \dfrac{-V_1}{sT}\$ and, \$V_3 = \dfrac{-V_2}{sT} = \dfrac{V_1}{s^2T^2}\$

You should be able to figure it out from there.

Regarding interpretation of sT and Q, there is nothing in your question that permits a further analysis.